# TableViewCell with gradient layer -> layout issues

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin, layout, gradient

I'm trying to add gradient for TableViewCell. I'm updating the gradient layer in LayoutSubview(). When I debug it looks like it sets correct value for layer frame. But the gradient is not "redrawn" or something as on each rotation the gradient is displayed with size for previous orientation. What I'm doing wrong?

```
public override void AwakeFromNib()
    {
        base.AwakeFromNib();

        _gradient = new CAGradientLayer();
        _gradient.Frame = ContentView.Bounds;
        _gradient.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red.CGColor;
        _gradient.StartPoint = new CGPoint(0, 0);
        _gradient.EndPoint = new CGPoint(1, 1);
        _gradient.Colors = new[] { _topColor, _bottomColor };
        this.ContentView.Layer.InsertSublayer(_gradient, 0);
    }

    public override void LayoutSubviews()
    {
        _gradient.Frame = ContentView.Bounds;
        base.LayoutSubviews();
    }
```

Comment: Do you have `preparreForSubView` in your cell and reset gradient layer or remove from it?

Comment: put your codes inside drawrect method instead of awakeFromNib

Comment: Can you show a screenshot or something to see what the issue is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved layer update from LayoutSubview to Draw as suggested by @dip

```
    public override void Draw(CGRect rect)
    {
        _gradient.Frame = ContentView.Bounds;
        base.Draw(rect);
    }
```

The layout is working now.